# Ext JS 4: same container in every tab

Tags: class, extjs, tabs, extjs4, containers

I am currently using extjs 4 and have a tab panel of about 4 tabs and I want to put the same container which contains two toolbars inside each tab. However, whenever I try to do this, it will only add the container to the last tab and leave the first three empty. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
function createTabPanel(config) {
    return new Ext.Panel(Ext.apply({
        region: 'center',
        dockedItems: [
                dateToolbar,
                saveToolbar
        ]
    }, config));
};

var tabPanel = createTabPanel({
});

function createTabContainer(config) {
    return new Ext.Container(Ext.apply({
        height: 500,
        layout: 'border',
        items: tabPanel
    }, config));
};

var tab1Container = createTabContainer({
});

var tab2Container = createTabContainer({
});

var tab3Container = createTabContainer({
});

var tab4Container = createTabContainer({
});

var tabs = new Ext.tab.Panel ({    region: 'center',
title: 'Title:',
activeTab: 0,      // First tab active by default
bodyStyle: 'padding: 5px',
items: [
    {
        title: 'tab1',
        items: tab1container
    },
    {
        title: 'tab2',
        items: tab2container
    },
    {
        title: 'tab3',
        items: tab3container
    },
    {
        title: 'tab4',
        items: tab4container
    }
]
})


displayPanel = new Ext.Panel({
    renderTo : 'box_main',
    border: false,
    items: tabs
});
```

I believe I have to make a class and instantiate a new object every time I reuse the container but Im having trouble getting it to work. Any help would be great Thanks

EDIT: Added my container and tab panel. removed id, didnt fix it. 'dateToolbar', and 'saveToolbar' are two toolbars with combo boxes and buttons.

Answer (score 3):

You have one instance of `tabPanel`. Every component instance can have one parent container. You should modify your `createTabContainer` function like this:

```
function createTabContainer(config) {
    return new Ext.Container(Ext.apply({
        height: 500,
        layout: 'border',
        items: createTabPanel({})
    }, config));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to show your tabcontainer. But it's probably the id attribute - remove it.

Comment: Edited above, removing the id didn't fix it.

Comment: works for me - some syntax cleanup, also changed how you are adding the last panel. http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/8f8EC/